# Do NPC's perform their daily routine while you're gone?

Tags: fallout-3

Let's say I decide to kill a NPC by placing a mine next to their bed so they trip it when they wake up. Now let's say I decide to leave and wander while I wait for time to pass instead of using the wait function.

Will the [Radiant AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_AI) still execute when I'm not there or will it be a [Schrödinger's Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) style situation; the AI will do nothing until I look at it, at which point it will act according to Radiant AI?

Comment: Comment because I have no source or distance, but there is almost certainly a distance limit for the NPC to be active. When you get close enough, the NPC spawns where they should be for that time of day given other game states (plot points, npcs alive). It would be too taxing on the system to have every NPC in the entire game world performing a daily routine all the time, collision checking for mines and all other objects. They almost certainly unload when you get far enough away and reload when you come close again

Comment: For whether it matters or not in gameplay aspect.. Going off the example put forth by sommerjj: if that NPC, who "sleeps" in the bed they set up the mine up by, is a quest-giver or has an important function (like the nuka cola girl) then if they die when you're not around but still by your hand/methods, then the dead NPC, which used to give quests or rewards for certain objects, is no longer a part of the game and has a **HUGE** impact on gameplay.

Comment: @fbueckert Which is pretty much exactly what we're here for!

Comment: The OP has already given an easy way to test this.. plant the mine => leave => wait a day cycle (wait for when they should have got up and gone back to sleep) => go check.. if they are on the walls instead of in bed i think you have your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPC's do in fact go on with their daily routine when your somewhere else in the game, to prove it place a mine where an *unimportant* NPC is likely walk. after a while you could be on the otherside of the capital wasteland and would randomly get a karma Lost Notification because that person has died.